# Handlebars render only some elements

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following handlebars template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{log model}}
  <button {{action 'getSuggestion'}}>Get suggestion</button>
  {{log suggestion}}
  {{#if suggestion}}
    <p>There is a suggestion</p>
  {{else}}
    <p>NO suggestion</p>
  {{/if}}

  <ul>
  {{#each item in model}}
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Currently, the two `log` work as expected, but the button between them is **not** rendered.

A while ago I've added another `<p>text</p>` right in the beginning of the template and again, it didn't render.

Do you have any idea why? And is there a specific way to debug Ember applications? I find Handlebars extremely unpredictive, with elements being rendered or not after no specific reason, and with no errors shown...

Comment: there are ember developer tools plugins available for most browsers

Comment: Why have the button between the log statements?

Comment: I am using the Ember inspector, but it doesn't help me with what elements are rendered in templates (or at least I don't know where to look).

Comment: @KevinBoucher, I don't have it between, I just log a variable before the button and one after the button.

Comment: I could not reproduce http://jsbin.com/kejivuketa/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Oh darn, it seemed I was using some other version of Ember. With the latest one, it finally works as expected...thanks for pointing me out in your jsbin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was pretty simple: I was using a somewhat older version of Ember.js. Updating to the latest one made everything work again.